# SQL - Replace string function is not working as intended

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple string; for example,'01023201580001'.

I would like to replace the last two characters of this string; '01', with '00'.

I could extract the last two characters from this string as `RIGHT(columname,2)` and then use

```
REPLACE([columname], RIGHT([columname], 2), '00') as newColumnString
```

But in the result, it replaces the first two characters as well?

Expected result:  010232015800**00**

Result I get: **00**0232015800**00**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not Oracle. Which RDBMS are you using? mySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to the `replace()` function defines a *pattern* to match. The function will look for *all* instances of that pattern in the target string (first argument) and replace them with the replacement text (third argument).

If you know you only need to change the last two characters, you can take the value excluding those characters and then append the characters you want:

```
select left(columname, len(columname) - 2) + '00';
```

If you are doing this for an entire column and some of the rows might not end with '01', you can filter those out:

```
update MyTable
set    columname = left(columname, len(columname) - 2) + '00'
where  columname like '%01';
```

You could also use [`stuff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL server, you can use substring like so:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(20) = N'01023201580001';
DECLARE @ReplaceWith NVARCHAR(20) = N'00';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 0, LEN(@s) - 1) + @ReplaceWith;
```

Output: 01023201580000